# case insensitive awk vlookup

Tags: awk, ksh

I'm trying to do a case insensitive vlookup using awk for 1st column in a file , but its ignoring IGNORECASE and not matching in lowercase also using same awk how to compare 3rd column

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$3","$4;next} {print (($1 in a) ? $0","a[$1] : $0",NA,NA");}'

cat f1.txt
FOO,LONDON,45,789
goo,US,46,9876

cat f2.txt
FOO,LONDON,45,789
GOO,US,46,9876


awk -F, 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} FNR==NR{a[$1]=$3","$4;next} {print (($1 in a) ? $0","a[$1] : $0",NA,NA");}' f1.txt f2.txt

FOO,LONDON,45,789,45,789
GOO,US,46,9876,NA,NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following excerpt from `GNU Awk` page,

> Another method, specific to gawk, is to set the variable IGNORECASE to a nonzero value (see Built-in Variables). When IGNORECASE is not zero, all regexp and string operations ignore case.
>
> In general, you cannot use IGNORECASE to make certain rules case insensitive and other rules case sensitive, as there is no straightforward way to set IGNORECASE just for the pattern of a particular rule.17 To do this, use either bracket expressions or *tolower()*. However, one thing you can do with IGNORECASE only is dynamically turn case sensitivity on or off for all the rules at once.

So use the `GNU Awk's` `tolower()` function for your input as,

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[tolower($1)]=$3","$4;next} {print ((tolower($1) in a) ? $0","a[tolower($1)] : $0",NA,NA");}' f1.txt f2.txt
FOO,LONDON,45,789,45,789
GOO,US,46,9876,46,9876
```

Comment: Yep it works ( got a reference online ignorecase wont work on arrays)  , how to pattern match for 3rd column instead of first column

Comment: @ Inian , how to pattern match for 3rd column instead of first column . but both file has mixed combination of upper and lower case letters , in this case it converts to lowercase and performs a match .

Comment: @sam_84: It is a totally new  question beyond the scope of this. Can you ask it as a new one with you input and required output?